# Gnuplot percentage difference between 2 months

Tags: gnuplot, percentage

i have a csv file from 5 year malware data collected there are 2 columns the dates and the ips every date have 1 or more ips example

```
1/5/2013 12.234.123
1/5/2013 45.123.566
1/5/2013 100.546.12
1/6/2013 42.153.756
3/4/2014 75.356.258 etc... (every day for 5 years)
```

now i am trying to get the percentage difference between every month example:

```
November 2014 - 10%
December 2014 - 15%
```

i tried to put the percentage on y axis and in x2 axis but im getting some crazy results i am new to gnuplot and im still learning it here is the code i have right now:

```
set title 'Results Per Month'
set xlabel 'Date'
set ylabel 'Percentage'
set terminal png size 2800,900
set datafile sep ','
set xdata time

set timefmt '%Y/%m/%d'
set xrange['2009/3/22':'2014/12/02']
set xtics 30*24*60*60
set format x '%Y/%m'

set autoscale x2fix
set x2tics 
set x2range[0:*]
set format x2 "%g %%"

set xtics nomirror rotate by -90
set grid ytics xtics
set ytics 10
set yrange [0:*]
set term png
set output 'file.png'

plot 'export.csv' using (timecolumn(1) - (tm_mday(timecolumn(1))-1)*24*60*60):(1) smooth frequency w lp pt 7 ps 2 notitle, \
'' using (($1-$2)/$1*100):x2ticlabels(2) axes x2y1 with points ps 2 lw 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use some external script for such kind of preprocessing (you can also do this on-the-fly). Yes, you can do this in gnuplot in two steps, but can become quite complicated and requires some more profound knowledge of gnuplot.

Here is a working script, but I won't go into detail about the many different aspects of the actual implementation:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y/%m/%d'
set datafile separator ','

set table 'temporaryfile.dat'
set format x '%Y/%m/%d'
plot 'export.csv' using (timecolumn(1) - (tm_mday(timecolumn(1))-1)*24*60*60):(1) smooth frequency 
unset table

set y2tics
set ytics nomirror
set timefmt '"%Y/%m/%d"'
set format x '%b %Y'
set xtics rotate by 90 right

set datafile separator white
set yrange[0:*]
x0=x1=0
plot 'temporaryfile.dat' using 1:(strcol(3) eq "i" ? $2 : 1/0) w lp pt 7 ps 2 title 'IP count', \
     '' using 1:(x1=x0, x0=$2, strcol(3) eq "i" ? ($0 == 0 || x0 == 0 ? 0 : (x0-x1)/x0 * 100.0) : 1/0) axes x1y2 w lp title 'percentual change'
```

Basically, first you plot the result data of `smooth frequency` into a second data file. Then you can plot this, and to the calculations for the percentages.

Please note, that I used a timeformat which corresponds to your test data (and the data of your previous question), which doesn't correspond with what you have in your script! Please pay attention to this.

Also note, that the timefmt before the actual plot must be extended by quote signs which are written around the dates in `tmp.dat`.

Finally, the `strcol(3) eq 'i'` is necessary to circumvent a gnuplot bug, which causes a last line to be written with invalid data.

[image]

Comment: thanks alot i tun from terminal a .conf file i try your code and i get a error: "test.conf", line 6: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
plot 'e.dat' using (timecolumn(1) - (tm_mday(timecolumn(1))-1)*24*60*60):(1) smooth frequency 
                                                                                              ^
"test.conf", line 6: x range is invalid

Comment: As I wrote: it should work with the test data you posted, which seems to be different from what you really have. Since I can't guess which version is correct, you must adapt this part of the timefmt yourself.

Comment: So what's the problem with adapting the script?

Comment: im running the code you gived above and the script delete all data inside the csv file after running and im getting this error in the terminal: "test.conf", line 6: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

plot 'export.csv' using (timecolumn(1) - (tm_mday(timecolumn(1))-1)*24*60*60):(1) smooth frequency 
                                                                                                   ^
"test.conf", line 6: x range is invalid

Comment: The script uses two different file names! See the update for a completely predigested script...

Comment: oh i didnt notice that file names are different ok i fixed the file names but still i am getting some bad results and the file that script creates 'temporaryfile.dat' have inside only few dates here is a pic: http://i.imgur.com/wrJWtxh.png

Comment: Use the whole updated script, which also takes into account your actual timefmt (year/month/day), and the comma-separated fields in your input file (the output file has white-space separated fields).

Comment: thanks alot this is what i was looking for just one more think i cant understand the percentage line it doest show any spesific %: http://i.imgur.com/QQjR2QM.png

Comment: Because you haven't set the format properly. Use something like `set format y2 '%g%%'`.

Comment: cool i set the format in y2 and also i used range [0:*] i got the right percentage the only problems is that i get only 2 months every year i wanted all months of the years, 1 question in order to get that i want (the script) requires gnuplot "pro" knowledge ? thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67207/discussion-between-user2904051-and-christoph).

Comment: thatnks alot for helping me i want to learn how i can optimize the code myself i see you have great skills in gnuplot and this language is a bit differend that others so if possible may you explain me what exactly this plot does?                                                                                            plot 'temporaryfile.dat' using 1:(strcol(3) eq "i" ? $2 : 1/0) w lp pt 7 ps 2 title 'IP count', \
     '' using 1:(x1=x0, x0=$2, strcol(3) eq "i" ? ($0 == 0 || x0 == 0 ? 0 : (x0-x1)/x0 * 100.0) : 1/0) axes x1y2 w lp title 'percentual change'