# gnuplot emits bad file format error when set table command is used

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to get part of the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27534509/257924 to work but am running into a `Bad format character` error.

Only when I comment out the `set table` command below, do I get the error (execute this as a script on Linux). Below, I'm expecting `/tmp/temporaryfile.dat` to be generated and not a plot image file:

```
#!/bin/bash

datafile=/tmp/mydata.1
cat > $datafile <<EOF
  2013/5/1 1
  2013/5/1 1
  2013/5/1 1
  2013/6/1 2
  2013/6/1 2
EOF

gnuplot_in=/tmp/gnuplot.in
gnuplot_out=/tmp/gnuplot.png
cat > $gnuplot_in <<EOF
  set xdata time
  set timefmt '%Y/%m/%d'
  set table '/tmp/temporaryfile.dat'
  set format x '%Y/%m/%d'
  plot "$datafile" using (timecolumn(1)):2 title "thetitle" with linespoints;
  unset table
EOF

# Show the input with line numbers for debugging:
grep -n '.*' $gnuplot_in

gnuplot $gnuplot_in
#eog $gnuplot_out
```

The error is:

```
1:  set xdata time
2:  set timefmt '%Y/%m/%d'
3:  set table '/tmp/temporaryfile.dat'
4:  set format x '%Y/%m/%d'
5:  plot "/tmp/mydata.1" using (timecolumn(1)):2 title "thetitle" with linespoints;
6:  unset table
"/tmp/gnuplot.in", line 5: Bad format character
```

I've already checked the script for accidental UNICODE characters as indicated by [gnuplot error: Bad format character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342483/gnuplot-error-bad-format-character)

What would cause this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: the error message means that there is an error in one of the format strings given in the previous lines, e.g. an unknown format specifier. I suspect that your actual script lacks the "xdata time" command, because it works alright with me, both with gnuplot 4.6 and 5.0.1. v.5.0.rc2 available in ubuntu has problem with the syntax of timecolumn()

Comment: @KarlRatzsch: Thanks: That led me to check different systems, hence my posted answer. I did not try modifying the script to add "xdata time".

Answer (score 0):

I've concluded that this is due to a bug in the version of gnuplot on my RHEL 6.6 machine. On my RHEL 6.6 machine we have this version of gnuplot:

```
gnuplot 4.2 patchlevel 0
```

On my Debian system, the script works without errors, using this version of gnuplot:

```
gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0
```